# Augment an array using ORM objects

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I'm simply attempting to augment an array in Symfony like thus;

```
$inputters = $project->getInputters();
foreach($inputters as $in){
   $ab[] = $in->getName();
}
```

`$project` is a Symfony *entity*. It turns out when I var dump `$ab[]` I actually get two separate arrays? Like thus:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Bob Right"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "Sally Brown"
}
```

for example. But what I'm really after is a single array, like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Bob Right",
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Sally Brown"
}
```

for instance. The `$project->getInputters()` method returns a collection. Like:

**Project**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="inputterProjects")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="project_inputters",
*     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
*     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
* )
* @var ArrayCollection<int,User>
*/
private $inputters;


/**
* @return Collection
*/
public function getInputters(): Collection
{
   return $this->inputters;
}
```

Why is this simple array augmentation producing two separate arrays when I'm expecting only one?

Help.

**edits**;

```
foreach($inputters as $in){
  $ab[] = is_array($in->getName());
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

**edits1**

```
foreach($inputters as $in){
   $ab[] = get_class($in);
}

var_dump($ab);

array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "App\Entity\User" }
```

**User**

```
/**
* @return string
*/
public function getName(): string
{
   return $this->name;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `var_dump()` within the foreach loop? If so, you don't have 2 separate arrays, but you are calling 2 times the function

Comment: Outside the loop my friend

Comment: what does get_class($in) do ? and what is the content of the getName Method ?

Comment: My edits as above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My loop was inside an `array_map()` construct. I think this was the issue. Knocking it out of whack.